# compare 2 properties inside 2 linq lists and return a boolean based on the comparision

Tags: c#, linq

I've tried to find the answer to this but nothing seems to fit it quite right.

Requirement: From a known list of FooObjects, return a list of the Foo Id's whose data satisfies all the search criteria.

Here is my code:

```
class testClass
{
    public class SearchItem
    {
        string Term { get; set; }
        decimal Confidence { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooObject
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public List<Data> Data { get; set; }

    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public decimal Confidence { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var searchItems = new List<SearchTerm>
            {
                new SearchTerm{ Confidence = (decimal)1, Term = "TestWord" },
                new SearchTerm{ Confidence = (decimal)1, Term = "TestWord2" },

            };
        var FooObjects = new List<FooObject>
            {
                new FooObject{Id = new Guid(), Data = new List<Data>
                    {                                                                                     
                        new Data{Text = "TestWord", Confidence = 1}, 
                        new Data{Text = "TestWord2", Confidence = 1},                                                                                     
                        new Data{Text = "SomeOtherWord", Confidence = 1},                                                                                  
                    }
            }
        }; 
//result is a list of the Foo IDs
        var result = FooObjects.Where(foo => !searchItems.Select(item => item.Term).Except(foo.Data.Select(dt => dt.Text).Distinct()).Any())
                     .Select(foo => foo.Id).ToList();

        Assert.That(result.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        searchItems.Add(new SearchTerm{Term = "NotFoundString"});
        result = FooObjects.Where(foo => !searchItems.Select(item => item.Term).Except(foo.Data.Select(dt => dt.Text).Distinct()).Any())
      .Select(foo => foo.Id).ToList();

        Assert.That(result.Count, Is.EqualTo(0));
    }
}
```

I now need to modify this so that I can compare against the confidence of each  word

Question:
How do I modify the LINQ to compare the confidence and the Term against my data

Comment: updated example

Comment: Can you maybe reword your requirement so that you can convoy a clear idea of what you are trying to do? Because it appears to me that you just need to get your head out of the box and rephrase the idea for yourself as well

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I have updated the requirement, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching any criteria like @dymanoid said in his answer, you should be looking to satisfy all the search items/terms (you are mixing these up in your example code, be consistent).

```
var result = FooObjects
    .Where(f => searchItems.All(
        s => f.Data.Exists(d => d.Text == s.Term && d.Confidence == s.Confidence)))
    .Select(f => f.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
var result = FooObjects
    .Where(foo => foo.Data.Any(d => searchTerms.Any(
        si => d.Term == si.Text && d.Confidence == si.Confidence)))
    .Select(foo => foo.Id);
```

Keep in mind that this search isn't effective - if your data sets are large, the performance will be bad.